# Modify a published function in R

Tags: r, graphics

From page 6 of this publication [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8d3c/d65da1004df38051367c00bb0bd2962d8988.pdf), I found a very useful function. Thanks to the authors I was able to find lethal dose values easily. The function provides a line graph for an individual case treatment. But I have no idea of how to modify it to run probit analysis when comparing more than one treatment. In addition, is it possible to obtain a graph with different lines representing the different treatments?

For example when I run it with these:

```
## Treatment 1     
d <- c(0.00,6.25,12.50,25.00,50.00,100.00)    
x <- c(2,2,0,0,26,40)
t <- c(40,40,40,40,40,40)
lc(d,x,t)   

## Treatment 2  
d2 <- c(0.00,6.25,12.50,25.00,50.00,100)
x2 <- c(4,7,18,27, 35,40)
t2 <- c(40,40,40,40,40,40)
lc(d2,x2,t2)
```

I would like it to look this way:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to modify the function like so, in order to return the series to plot:

```
lc<-function(d,x,t){ # This function has three main entries that are the concentrations of effluents (d), the number of dead (x) after  treatment and the total number of species (t) that received effluent concentrations (lc)
  options(warn=-1) # This is to avoid warming alerts
  # The following function will compute the corrected mortality rates
  Abbott<-function(d,x,t){
    ab<-(1-((t-x)/(t[d==0]-x[d==0])))
    ifelse(ab < 0,0,ab[])}
  Abb<-Abbott(d,x,t)
  mynewdat<-data.frame(d,x,t,Abb); (mynewdat = mynewdat[!d==0,]) # This part removed the control which is no more useful for  the determination of lc
  mod<-list()
  #The following help to select the binomial family link
  family<-function (i){
    if (i==1){family=binomial(link = "probit")}
    else{
      if (i==2){family=binomial(link = "logit")}
      else{
        if (i==3){family=binomial(link = "cloglog")}
      }}
    #return(family)
  }
  for (i in 1:3){
    mod[[i]]<-glm(Abb ~ log(d), family=family(i), data=mynewdat)
  }
  b<-which.min(c(deviance(mod[[1]]), deviance(mod[[2]]), deviance(mod[[3]]))) # Compare and select the best link
  cat("The best model is the model", b,"\n") # Gives the output of the previous comparison
  out=list()
  out$Resum<-summary(mod[[b]])
  ld<-dose.p(mod[[b]],p=c(0.50,0.90,0.95)) # Computation of lethal concentrations 50, 90 and 95 but may also 10, 20, 80 etc…
  ld.ci <- ld+ attr(ld, "SE") %*% matrix(qnorm(1 - 0.05/2)*c(-1,1), nrow=1) # Defines the confidence intervals
  out$ld.est <- round(exp((cbind(ld, attr(ld, "SE"), ld.ci[,1], ld.ci[,2]))),3)
  dimnames(out$ld.est)[[2]] <- c("LD", "SE", "LCL","UCL") # Return the lethal concentrations and their confidence intervals
  #The following part plots the curve
  x1=seq(min(d),max(d), 0.001)
  lpredmod <- predict(mod[[b]], data.frame(d=x1), type="response")
  plot(d,Abb, pch=16, ylim=c(0,1),xlab="Concentration ", ylab = "Mortality rate")
  lines(x1,lpredmod)
  #Goodness of fit of the model
  out$comparison<-pchisq(deviance(mod[[b]]), mod[[b]]$df.residual, lower=FALSE) # Comparison of deviance
  out$R2_Naglekerke<-round((1-exp((mod[[b]]$dev-mod[[b]]$null)/sum(t)))/(1-exp(-mod[[b]]$null/sum(t))),3) #Determination of  Naglekerke R square
  out$x1 <- x1
  out$premod <- lpredmod
  return(out)
}
```

`lc` will now return the vqlues of `x1` and `lpremod`.

After that we can simply `plot` the mortality rates. You can tweak the plot as you want:

```
d<-c(0.00,6.25,12.50,25.00,50.00,100.00)     
x<-c(2,2,0,0,26,40)  
t<-c(40,40,40,40,40,40) 
d2<- c(0.00,6.25,12.50,25.00,50.00,100)  
x2<- c(4,7,18,27, 35,40)    
t2<- c(40,40,40,40,40,40)  
lc(d2,x2,t2)
model1 <- lc(d,x,t)
model2 <- lc(d2,x2,t2)
plot(as.numeric(model1$premod), t="l", pch=16, ylim=c(0,1),xlab="Concentration ", ylab = "Mortality rate")
lines(as.numeric(model2$premod), t="l", col="red")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Many thanks for helping out. I hesitated in appreciation thinking StackOverflow discourages that with this statement I saw: Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".